# How to change the return URL in Approval Process?

Tags: approval-process

A Manager can access all his Approval Items to be approved from his Home Page.

In Approval Request, If a Manager is approving/rejecting his subordinates' record, he  is redirected to the record he is approving/rejecting.

I want to change the return url to Home Page where all Items to Approve will be listed.